# How to use OXml with C++ Builder 10.1 Berlin Update 2 Starter

Tags: c++

I want to use the OXml component [(OXml website)](http://www.kluug.net/oxml.php/) with C++ Builder 10.1 Berlin Update 2 Starter. I asked arround in the newsgroups of Embarcadero, in the Community of Embarcadero, on the forum of the creator of OXml. But no-one replied. I am new at using components. I used the TXMLDocument in Turbo C++ Explorer which worked well. But now I want to use a modern developmenttool.

My question is basically: How do I use OXml in C++ Builder Starter. I installed it as a component which created .hpp and .dcu files. But how do I use it further. I looked at the .hpp files and every .hpp file has its own namespace. I want to read XML files and extract the data within them so I can use it in my programs.

Hope someone can give me some examples how to do this.

Greetings,

Don

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. You appear to asking for a tutorial. We're here to answer specific programming issues.

Comment: Can you give me another website where I can post my question? I tried already a few websites. But no-one responses.